# How is the positioning of labels attached to arrows calculated by the tikz-cd package?

Tags: tikz-cd

I [recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24603822#24603822) bumped into a small problem while using the `tikz-cd` package. It was about the positioning of the labels attached to certain arrows. One of the users in chat was friendly enough to point out to me that the positioning can be manually controlled using `pos=<fraction>`.

Upon implementing this fix, I discovered that the behavior as I varied my input for `<fraction>` was quite remarkable and counter-intuitive. I would have naively expected for the fraction to correspond, in the obvious way, to the fraction of arrow-length. Some experimenting shows that, for straight arrows, this indeed seems to be the case. However, for bent arrows it doesn't seem so simple. As a (minimal working) example, consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
      A \arrow[r,bend left=30,"\pi" pos=<fraction>]&B
    \end{tikzcd}
  \]
\end{document}
```

Inserting .4 and .6 for `<fraction>` yields the following two outputs:

[image: Outputs for .4 and .6]

which certainly do not correspond to the label being placed 40% and 60% along the length of the arrow. My (obvious) question is: *What do the numbers represent? How are they used to determine where to place the labels (especially in the apparently non-trivial bent-arrow case)?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maintainer of the package [has responded to a message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=26438944#26438944) about this problem---it turns out to be intended behavior.

---

### Original answer

I would consider that a bug and would advice you to report this. 
You can use the following example:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[bend left=60,"\mid" pos=.1,"\mid" pos=.2,"\mid" pos=.3,"\mid" pos=.4,"\mid" pos=.5,"\mid" pos=.6,"\mid" pos=.7,"\mid" pos=.8,"\mid" pos=.9]{r} & B\\
    A \arrow[bend left=30,"\mid" pos=.1,"\mid" pos=.2,"\mid" pos=.3,"\mid" pos=.4,"\mid" pos=.5,"\mid" pos=.6,"\mid" pos=.7,"\mid" pos=.8,"\mid" pos=.9]{r} & B\\
    A \arrow["\mid" pos=.1,"\mid" pos=.2,"\mid" pos=.3,"\mid" pos=.4,"\mid" pos=.5,"\mid" pos=.6,"\mid" pos=.7,"\mid" pos=.8,"\mid" pos=.9]{r} & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I would report it to `tikz-cd` as this seems not to be a problem of Ti*k*Z itself. Just see this (sorry, ugly) code:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (1) {A};
    \node (2) [right = of 1] {B};
    \path[every node/.append style=above] (1) edge[bend left=60] node [pos=.1] {$\mid$} node [pos=.2] {$\mid$} node [pos=.3] {$\mid$} node [pos=.4] {$\mid$} node [pos=.5] {$\mid$} node [pos=.6] {$\mid$} node [pos=.7] {$\mid$} node [pos=.8] {$\mid$} node [pos=.9] {$\mid$} (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't really know how and/or where to report this. Would you enlighten me?

Comment: @Danu You could try to ping the maintainer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12744/flor%C3%AAncio-neves Here in comment or in chat. Or you ask the friendly maintainers of CTAN to forward an e-mail for you. Unluckily, I am not able to find any contact information myself.

Comment: @Danu any news on this? I had this problem again on http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296565

Comment: Yes, [Florencio responded](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=26438944#26438944) to a ping in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `tikz-cd`places the label box to the `right of the insertion point` instead of centring it at that point.

Here is a code that allows the comparison with `pstricks` (its `psmatrix` environment is an alternative to `tikz-cd`). I successively placed the label box centred (default), to the left and to the right of the insertion point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
      A \arrow[r,bend left=30,"\pi" pos=0.6]&B
    \end{tikzcd}
  \]

\psset{linewidth=0.6pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, nodesepA=4.5pt, nodesepB=4.5pt, arcangle=35, shortput=nab, tpos=0.6, labelsep=3pt}
\[ \begin{psmatrix}[colsep = 1.15cm]
 [name=A] A & [name=B] B
 \ncarc{A}{B}^{\scriptstyle\pi}
    \end{psmatrix}
    \]%

\[ \begin{psmatrix}[colsep = 1.15cm]
 [name=A] A & [name=B] B
 \ncarc{A}{B}^{\makebox[0pt][r]{\scriptstyle\pi $}}
    \end{psmatrix}
    \]%

\[ \begin{psmatrix}[colsep = 1.15cm]
[name=A] A & [name=B] B
 \ncarc{A}{B}^{\makebox[0pt][l]{\scriptstyle\pi $}}
    \end{psmatrix}
    \]%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what has this to do with the question?

Comment: I explained how tikz seems to position the label box (by the left-hand side, not by its centre, nor its right-hand side), as can be clearly seen from the comparison with what we can produce with pstricks.  It confirms @Larifari's point of view: this is a bug, as the sensible positioning would be to use the centre.