# split exact sequence in tikz

Tags: tikz-cd

Is there an easy way to draw a split exact sequence in tikz cd (that is, with an arrow going from A to B, and a reverse arrow going from B to A)? There is obviously a way to do this with the full tikz, but this is a little painful...

**EDIT** to answer the comment, the picture should look something like this:

[image]

(just the T-> PO part, Except I would prefer the back arrow to curve less)

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please elaborate on what you want drawn?  Perhaps find an illustration or draw one.

Comment: @JP-Ellis I added an illustration, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing which could not be found in the `tikz-cd`-manual, but here you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    0\arrow{r} & \mathbb{R}\arrow{r}{t}\arrow{d}{\mathcal{P}} & X\arrow{r}{\pi}\arrow{d}{s} & G\arrow{r}\arrow[equal]{d} & 0 \\
    0\arrow{r} & \mathbb{T}\arrow{r}{r} & \text{PO}\arrow{r}\arrow[bend left=33]{l}{\varphi} & G\arrow{r} & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you want to reduce the bending radius, I have put the label `r` above. If you want the look of your screenshot, just do `\arrow{r}[swap]{r}`!

If you want to have a bending less than 33, you will encounter [this bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271995).

Comment: Thanks! I actually did not see anything exactly like this in the manual (and so I was afraid of all sorts of unpleasantness).